# Adding values or adding new tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples such as:

```
tuplist = [('New York', 546), ('Chicago', 675)]
```

And new tuples to either add to the list or sum, according to the [0] index:

```
tup3 = ('New York', 655)
tup4 = ('Los Angeles', 1273)
```

To get:

```
[('New York', 1201), ('Chicago', 675), ('Los Angeles', 1273)]
```

I'm creating these lists as growing values in a dict as I loop through a CSV.  So if the above represents `{'Apples': [(City1, Number1), (City2, Number2)]}`,  I currently use:

```
if fruit not in city_fruitd:
    city_fruitd[fruit] = [(city, count)]
else:
    city_fruitd[fruit] += [(city, count)]
```

How do I instead check for existing cities and sum accordingly if the city already exists?

Comment: why not instead of a tuple use a counter dic and you can add the new values a lot easier

Comment: Must that really be "a list of tuples"? Your job would be easier if that were a dictionary, such as `{'New York': 546, 'Chicago': 675}`.

Comment: But it is a dictionary.  Or do you mean I should have a dictionary of dictionaries instead of a dictionary of tuple lists?  I get confused at creating {'Apples': {City1: Number1, City2: Number2}}.  In fact, later in the code, I am  making a dictionary out of the tuples, but only in a way where I can digest one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check for the case where the city is in the list of cities:

```
city in [x[0] for x in city_fruitd[fruit]]
```

Then find this city index

```
index = [city_fruitd[fruit].index(x) for x in city_fruitd[fruit] if city == x[0]][0]
```

And assign it the added value

```
city_fruitd[fruit][index] = [(city, city_fruitd[fruit][index][1] + count)]
```

So:

```
if fruit not in city_fruitd:
    city_fruitd[fruit] = [(city, count)]
elif city in [x[0] for x in city_fruitd[fruit]]:
    index = [city_fruitd[fruit].index(x) for x in city_fruitd[fruit] if city == x[0]][0]
    city_fruitd[fruit][index] = [(city, city_fruitd[fruit][index][1] + count)]
else:
    city_fruitd[fruit] += [(city, count)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using defaultdict as discussed in the comments:

```
from collections import defaultdict

#Initialize the defualt dict
tupdict = defaultdict(int)

#Add existing tuple list to default dict
tuplist = [('New York', 546), ('Chicago', 675)]
tupdict.update(tuplist)

#Add tuples one at a time to tupdict
tup3 = ('New York', 655)
tup4 = ('Los Angeles', 1273)

#Simple function to make it easier to add tuples
def add_tup(tupdict, to_add):
    k,v = to_add
    tupdict[k] += v

add_tup(tupdict, tup3)
add_tup(tupdict, tup4)

#Convert dict back to tuples
tuplist = tupdict.items()
print(tuplist)
```

Output:

```
[('New York', 1201), ('Los Angeles', 1273), ('Chicago', 675)]
```